# Can i store string in char array of length 1

Tags: c

I'm a comfortable programmer in Java. But I have a hard time grasping some concepts of C.

I came across some C code online that stored a string in char array of length 1.

```
char a[0] = 'abcd';
```

In Java. it is not possible at all. But could someone please tell me whether this is possible in C?

If yes, please briefly explain.

In java, if I need to store an array of strings, I will do

```
String[] a = new String[1]; a[0] = "text";
```

Now, I need to do this exact thing in C, with array size 1.

Comment: Your text says length 1, but your array is declared with length 0, which is not valid. And `'abcd'` is not a string, it's a `char`. Strings use double quotes.

Comment: In C, a string is an array of characters terminated by a zero byte. So in order to store a string of length N, you need an array of at least N+1.

Comment: Bro, please tell me how to store a string in char array at the index 0.

Comment: @AlexSparrow what do you mean "store a string in char array at the index 0"?

Comment: Also, if your example given is from online, could you please link the source for context?

Comment: If you're trying to assign to index 0, you don't put the datatype before the array name. That makes it a declaration, not an assignment.

Comment: If you want to learn C, you should pick up a textbook or tutorial, this isn't the way to do it.

Comment: In java, if i need to store array of string, I will do. ```String[] a = new String[1]; a[0] = "text";``` Now, I need to do this exact thing in C, with array size 1.

Comment: @Barmar that would make a lot more sense (would like OP to confirm tho). I was thrown off by his example.

Comment: @AlexSparrow that makes much more sense, I'll edit my answer to show that.

Comment: In C you would write `char **a = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1); a[0] = "text";`

Comment: `char *` is a single string, `char **` is a pointer to an array of strings.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Barmar and Coffee Table Espresso. I will look further.

Comment: Or you can do `char *a[1]; a[0] = "text";`

Comment: Basically, Java `String` == C `char *`

Comment: @AlexSparrow I've edited my answer to show how to do it. Please accept it if it solves your issue

Comment: @Barmar, `char *` is *not* "a string". It is a pointer to a "char". It may point to the first `char` in a string, but doesn't have to.

Comment: @HAL9000 I know, but for purposes of translation it serves a similar purpose.

Comment: @HAL9000 OP couldn't even figure out that a char array wasn't the same as a string array in Java. I think giving him a rough idea of what a char array is is helpful in this case.

Comment: Arrays of length `1` doesn't make any sense in `c`.  Declaring an array `foo a[1]` has basically the same memory layout as `foo a;`. You are just adding some syntactic salt.

Comment: @HAL9000 you're right, there's no real point to it. However, it is what OP asked for.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso, I was refering to OP, should have been clearer about that.

Comment: @HAL9000 OP was very very unclear about the entire question honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, a string is a `char` array terminated by a NUL character. `char *` in C roughly corresponds to `String` in Java.

To do the C equivalent of `String[] a = new String[1]; a[0] = "string";` in C, you can do:

```
char *a[1];   // this will be stored on the stack so there's no need to allocate memory.
a[0] = "string";
```

Comment: This is not really equivalent to the Java operation - you're just storing the address of the first character of the string literal to `a[0]`.  You're not actually creating a new string *instance*.

Comment: @JohnBode what? I've made an array of `char *` called `a`. (1st line) Then I've assigned a string literal to the first element of the array (2nd line)

Comment: all you've done is assigned the *address* of the first character of the literal to `a[0]`.  You haven't created a new instance of the string the way the Java code does.

Comment: @JohnBode OP clearly doesn't know C. He is asking about making an array from string literals. He probably does not understand the difference between making a new string instance with malloc and using the string literal, and probably doesn't even need  a new instance.

Comment: @JohnBode by your logic I should make a "String" struct and heap allocate a bunch of stuff in order to be "equivalent" to the Java operation.

Comment: no, you should use `malloc` to create a new buffer to store the string in and assign that address to `a[0]` - that's closer to what the Java code is doing.  I realize the OP doesn't know C, but your example is misleading.

Comment: @JohnBode I'd say yours is more misleading because it's going to encourage OP to copy around a bunch of string literals needlessly. If OP doesn't know C at all, he likely doesn't know low level memory details or how Java is going to handle string literals.

Comment: of course we can't really say who's "right" without knowing what OP actually needs this for

Comment: A bit nitpicking, but a string is not necessarily stored in a char array. `int32_t str[2] = {0x55555555, 0x00000000}; will yield the string "UUUU" without a char array. You can print it with puts((char*)str);

Answer (score 2):

You can store a string in a `char` array of length 1, but it has to be empty:

```
char a[1] = "";
```

The terminating null character is the only thing that can be stored.

If you want to do an array of strings in C, then do this:

```
char *a[1]; a[0] = "text";
```

Comment: If you read the comments asking for clarification, you can see that this is not what OP meant.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso That's not what the question is asking. If the comments are deleted, then any answer responding to them will be invalid.

Comment: you're right, someone should edit the question to be more in line with what OP is actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1. `'abcd'` is not a *string* - it is a multi-byte character constant, and the behavior of that is *entirely* implementation-specific.  Note that in C, character constants like `'A'` and `'\n'` have type `int`, not `char`.

   The declaration `char a[0]` is invalid - if a constant expression is used for the array size (as it is here), it *must* be greater than 0.  This is a constraint violation and the compiler is *required* to issue a diagnostic (although it doesn't have to halt translation).

   A *string* is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator.  Strings are stored in arrays of character type (`char` or `wchar_t` for "wide" strings), and the array must be large enough to accommodate the 0 terminator - IOW, an N-character string requires an array that's *at least* N+1 characters wide to store it in.

   C does not mandate any bounds checking on array writes or accesses. If you try to store a 100 character string to an array that's only 10 elements wide, those additional 90 characters are going to be written to the memory immediately following the end of the array, potentially clobbering something important.  You will not get an ArrayOutOfBounds exception.  Depending on what gets overwritten, you may get a runtime error.

   String literals like `"Hello"` have storage set aside for them at program startup and are held until the program terminates.  String literals are *supposed* to be immutable (like strings in Java), but there are platforms where the storage for string literals is writable.  The behavior on attempting to modify the contents of a string literal is *undefined* - it's erroneous, but the compiler is not required to handle it in any particular way.  It may work as expected, it may leave the string unmodified, it may crash, you may get a diagnostic, the compiler may halt translation, etc.

So, in summary, you cannot store anything but an empty string (i.e., the 0 terminator) in a character array that's 1 element wide.

From your comment:

> In java, if i need to store array of string, I will do. `String[] a = new String[1]; a[0] = "text";` Now, I need to do this exact thing in C, with array size 1.

The equivalent in C would be:

```
char *a[1];                             // a is a 1-element array of *pointer* to char
a[0] = malloc( strlen( "text" ) + 1 );  // malloc allocates memory from the heap and returns its address
if ( a[0] )
  strcpy( a[0], "text" );               // copy the contents of the literal to the heap memory
```

Here, you allocate some memory from the heap, store the address of that newly-allocated memory to `a[0]`, then copy the string literal `"text"` into that new buffer.  Since C doesn't do automatic garbage collection, you'll need to manually free that memory when you're done with it:

```
free( a[0] );
```

Comment: Why strcpy?? Java string literals behave exactly like the c ones (except that writing attempts do not have undefined behaviour)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - Because the example Java code is creating a new string *instance* on the heap and assigning `”text”` to it.  This is the closest C equivalent.

Comment: OP's example from comments was `String[] a = new String[1]; a[0] = "text";`

Answer (score -1):

Well, no. It is not possible.
In fact, there are many wrong things with the code you posted.

First of all, you cannot declare a char array of size zero, because all char arrays (i.e. Strings) are `NULL` terminated, what this means is that they end with a whole zero byte so even if you want to have an empty string you would do

`char empty[1] = "";`

Also, in C language there exists a concrete difference between `char` and `string`. Chars are written as `'a'` and strings are written as `"this is a string"` whereas in other programming languages like Python there's no such difference.

What you could do, but careful because this only works at the moment of declaring the variable, and to continue with your example is to declare it as follows

`char s[] = "abcd";`

If you want to go deeper, maybe you should probably look for information about `malloc()` function.

Comment: Character arrays don't have to be NUL terminated at all. It is perfectly valid to have a character array like so: `char s[4] = "abcd";`

Comment: *"you cannot declare a char array of size zero, because all char arrays (i.e. Strings) are NULL terminated,"* - Correct statement but wrong motivation. You cannot declare a char (or any type) array of size zero because the C standard says so. Note that this was not true in early C standards. And as Cheatah says, there is a difference between char arrays and strings.

Comment: Op is comfortable in java. In java there is a separate character type, op is just confused because the multibyte char constant which java does not have

Comment: @Cheatah it is actually valid to declare a char array as you said, but for what I understand char arrays are indeed NULL terminated by standard (or by default) you just don't have to do it yourself. For example, if we have `char s[] = "abcd";` you could just traverse it like this `while(s[i]){//do sth i++;}` and the loop's last execution will be with `s[3]` or 'd' cause after that it comes a whole zero byte. This is not the case for  an `int` array of size 4 in which case the while loop will continue to execute until you find a zero value.

Comment: @MarcoCardoso No, char arrays are NOT null terminated. Strings are null terminated and are (always in practice, but not necessarily) stored as char arrays.

Comment: @MarcoCardoso `int str[2] = {0x55555555, 0x00000000};` will yield the string "UUUU" without a char array on a 32 bit system. You can print it with `puts((char*)str);`